# ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies - Error with reading CSV file in Nest.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, nestjs, nest

Im trying to read an uploaded CSV file in nest and get the following error

' ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AssetsController (AssetsService, ?). Please make sure that the argument CsvParser at index [1] is available in the AssetsModule context.'

I have imported the package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-csv-parser

```js
import {CsvParser} from 'nest-csv-parser'
```

Added the constructor

```js
constructor(private readonly csvParser: CsvParser) {}
```

Created the entity

```js
class Asset {
    assetID: string;
    assetName: string;
    assetType: string;
    assetDescription: string;
    assetLocation: string;
    assetImage: string;
    assetStatus: string;
    assetNotes: string;
    assetClientID: string;
    assetSiteID: string;
    assetContractorID: string;
    assetMaintenanceID: string;
    assetDocumentID: string;
    assetCreated: string;
    assetUpdated: string;
    assetCreatedBy: string;
    assetUpdatedBy: string;
}
```

and my function looks like so

```js
 @Get('import')
    async parseCSVFile()
    {
        const csvPath = getCSVFile();
        console.log(" => ", csvPath);
        const stream = fs.createReadStream(csvPath)
        const entities: ParsedData<InstanceType<any>> = await this.csvParser.parse(stream, Asset)
        // You will get JSON
        console.log(entities);
    }
```

Module

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AssetsService } from './assets.service';
import { AssetsController } from './assets.controller';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AssetSchema } from 'assets/schemas/assets.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'Assets', schema: AssetSchema}])
  ],
  providers: [AssetsService],
  controllers: [AssetsController]
})
export class AssetsModule {}
```

I have been following along with [How do I read an uploaded file (text/.csv) using nestjs and Multer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71257348/how-do-i-read-an-uploaded-file-text-csv-using-nestjs-and-multer)

Comment: show us the nestjs module that has that registers that `AssetsController` controller

Comment: Edited my question and added the module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs of `nest-csv-parser`:

[image]

that `CsvParser` provider is registered and exported by `CsvModule`, thus you must import it into your `AssetsModule` module.

Comment: You're right, I had that import on the app.module - thank you